# I have a trouble counting steps with expo pedometer

Tags: react-native, expo, android-sensors, pedometer

I am using expo pedometer but I have two problems:

1. It doesn't seem to count the steps,the steps count is always zero.
2. The `Pedometer.getStepCountAsync` function isn't supported in android.

I am using

- "expo": "~44.0.0"
- "expo-sensors": "~11.1.0"
- "react": "17.0.1"
- "react-dom": "17.0.1"
- "react-native": "0.64.3"
- my mobile android version is 11

Here's my code

```js
import { Pedometer } from "expo-sensors";
export default function HomeScreen() {
  const [pedometerAvailability, setPedometerAvailability] = useState("");
  const [stepsCount, setStepsCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    subscribe();
    return () => {};
  }, []);

  const subscribe = () => {
    const subscription = Pedometer.watchStepCount((result) => {
      setStepsCount(result.steps);
    });

    Pedometer.isAvailableAsync().then(
      (result) => {
        setPedometerAvailability(String(result));
      },
      (error) => {
        setPedometerAvailability("Could not get isPedometerAvailable: " + error);
      }
    );
  };

  return (
   <Text>{stepsCount}</Text>
  )
}
```

Comment: Seems like Pedometer.watchStepCount() no more supported for  expo > 34.0

Answer (score 1):

just give permission to track steps

```
    const requestActivityPermission = async () => {
  try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION,
    );
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      Alert.alert("Start walking");
    } else {
      Alert.alert("permission denied");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).